# fhir-net-api (STU3) - DocumentReference POST parsing error

Tags: hl7-fhir

Using the fhir-net-api (STU3, ver - 0.93.4.0), when trying to POST a DocumentReference resource, the following error is generated when parsing the resource (body)-

"IndexedElement :  is not a correctly formatted Instant"

This is occurring when parsing the value  of the "Indexed" attribute, which is of "instant" datatype.

The value being passed is of the form - yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+-Offset.
For example - 2005-12-24T09:43:41+11:00

Is there a different format to be used when passing values to "instant" datatypes?

Comment: Same Issue With PUT Observation Also  We are passing issued element in the below format  "issued": "2017-09-13T15:33:19.987+00:00", it throws error "3000025 - IssuedElement :  is not a correctly formatted Instant, Children[8] :  is not a correctly formatted Instant, "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your code seems fine. Can I ask you to:

- Create an issue in the [.NET API tracker](https://github.com/ewoutkramer/fhir-net-api) so I can solve it and you'll be updated when I do.
- Try the latest (0.93.5-beta6) to see if it got solved already?

Comment: This issue seems to occurring for all Instant data types . As of Now I am Skipping the Validation by comparing the key to this specific validation error

Comment: Thanks Ewout, tried with version 0.93.5-beta6 - the issue is resolved